# how to get information about Fragmentation of index in SQL server 2005 by scripts

Tags: sql-server, indexing

how to get information about Fragmentation of index in SQL server 2005 by scripts

Answer (score 1):

You can find it [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/finding-fragmentation-of-an-index-and-fi).

Comment: i want scripts to list all index of using database to that i can make one script to rebuild or REORGANIZE them at once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your situation, but if you run that kind of a script on a live database you can get nasty performance problems while it is running.  If some of the indexes are badly fragmented, let's say more than 40-50%, then it becomes a better alternative to rebuild it.
But you can of course make that script something like:

```
DECLARE cur_idx CURSOR
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL , NULL, N'LIMITED')
WHERE avg_fragmentation_in_percent > @your_limit_for_fragmentation

OPEN CURSOR cur_idx

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_idx INTO @idx_name
WHILE @@FETCHSTATUS = 0 BEGIN
   --create dynamic sql statement 
END
```

--close cursor and clean up